# Rails current_user best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm on a dilema, a have a ton of objects associated to the current_user on my app. And and don't know if in my controllers i keep using the IDs to find these objects or put directly the current_user + object.

**Exemple:**

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController

 def show
      @house = House.find(params[:id]) **or?** @house = current_user.house 
    end

 def edit
      @house = House.find(params[:id]) **or?** @house = current_user.house 
    end
end
```

And this going on and on. thank's in advance

Comment: I would stick to using `params[:id]`. If at a later date you decided to add an extra feature, for example, administrators being able to edit any house, using `current_user.house` would prevent this.

Comment: so, for flexibility is better to keep the ID, yeah that's true, but you noticed that if you assign directly it feels that you earn performance?

Comment: On a simple case like this, you are *nowhere* near a place where you need to worry about performance.

Comment: but in this way don't improve the amount of querys on db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `House.find(params[:id])` you have a potential security hole, as a given user could simply change the number in the url and access the house for a different user.   So if you go this route, you have to add something to protect unathorized access.

OTOH, `current_user.house` keeps them on their own house, but needs alternate code for admin functions.

For simple applications, you can do this by hand, but for larger applications, you might want to consider authorization frameworks such as [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or [declarative_authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization)  where you can more easily define the permissions.

I use decl_auth myself, and all my controllers either use its method of loading the resource with `filter_resource_access` (loads the appropriate resource or throws and error if not allowed)  or by hand with `House.with_permissions_to(:index)`  which will only give me a house if I have permission to load it.

As always, Railscasts say it best: [cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) and [declarative authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization).